# Operation with values of a streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

It should be a simple thing, but I've been in this for days!

```
///StreamBuilder
StreamBuilder(
        stream: farmacos.orderBy("nome", descending: false).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return const Text("No data...");
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.amberAccent[100],
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_margem * .1,
                        _margem * .1, _margem * .1, _margem * .1),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [

                        ///Get data from the stream
    
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["nome"].toString()),        //Ex: Paracetamol
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_ml_Kg"].toString(),), //Ex: 40
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_max"].toString(),),   //Ex: 1000

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          );
        },
      ),
```

[Here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1mYC.png)

Now, I want to do a operation with the data, like this:

```
    Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["nome"].toString()),

       Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_ml_Kg"].toString(),),

  Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_max"].toString(),),
    
    _dose = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_ml_Kg"]*20, 

Text("$_dose"),
```

And the error is:

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

What's wrong where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant declare var inside children list
what you have to do is

```
streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
              _dose = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_ml_Kg"]*20;
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {}
                    ,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.amberAccent[100],

                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_margem * .1,
                        _margem * .1, _margem * .1, _margem * .1),

                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        ///Get data from the stream
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["nome"].toString()),        //Ex: Paracetamol
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_ml_Kg"].toString(),), //Ex: 40
                        Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["dose_max"].toString(),),
                        Text("$_dose"),//Ex: 1000
                        //Text("$_dose"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
              },
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Hello Artur Sikora. Thanks a lot for the help. In this place, the [index] gives an error! Maybe because it's being called before it's declared. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry. Just declare _dose under listview.builer just before return gestureDetector

Comment: Thanks Artur. Now it solved the problem. Take care.